# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

Tags: java

This is the error I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
    Scanner cannot be resolved to a type

    at hello.main(hello.java:11)
```

This is my code.

```
public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double area;
        double radius;  

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("반지름을 입력하시오: ");
        radius = input.nextDouble();
        area = 3.14 * radius * radius;

        System.out.println(area);
    }    
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported Scanner class like `import java.util.Scanner;`

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

at the top of your file.  You've got to import it.